# How to achieve gradient effect of DropShadowPanel in uwp?

Tags: uwp

This is what I currently achieve:

[image]

```xml
<!--xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"-->

<controls:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="30">
    <controls:DropShadowPanel.Color>
        <Color>Red</Color>
    </controls:DropShadowPanel.Color>
    <Rectangle Width="400" Height="50" RadiusX="25" RadiusY="25">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0.5" StartPoint="1,0.5" ColorInterpolationMode="ScRgbLinearInterpolation">
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.4"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.6"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

Since DropShadowPanel.Color is a Color property, not a Brush, I can't use LinearGradientBrush, so is there any way to achieve shadow gradient so that the shadow is consistent with Rectangle.Fill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `DropShadowPanel` has been deprecated, and gradient shadows also cannot be implemented in the latest [Attached Shadows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/attachedshadows).

You can see the [source code here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/77b009ddf591b78dfc5bad0088c99ce35406170b/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Shadows/IAttachedShadow.cs#L36), there are only solid color settings, and no gradient effect is provided. If you need to achieve gradient shadow effects, you may need to add functions to the source code.

It is recommended that you ask about this feature in [WindowsCommunityToolkit Github](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues).